# A Codenames challenge. What was the clue?

Tags: word, knowledge

Here is the scenario. The other day I watched two excellent well informed teams playing Codenames.

Amazingly the first team got six out of nine in their first attempt! The three words remaining for them were

> Mud
>
> Fact
>
> Deep
>
> The assassin was:  Bulb

The other team was faced with a real possibility that if they don't get all the 8 words then the opponent could win in the next attempt.

> The Spymaster after a lot of thinking said:
>
> ______ , 8

The word he said had a single vowel (used once)

What was his clue? The words are below.

> COLLEGE
>
> SCARY
>
> EGYPT
>
> TENNIS
>
> MUSIC
>
> DREAM
>
> ENGLAND
>
> LEAD

The clue word, as it turns out, had a very good connection to all words.

Assume the Innocent Bystanders were irrelevant to his answer

Please comment if this is too broad. I will restrict it further.

Please no partial answers.

Comment: Probably needs a trivia tag.

Comment: Could not find one

Comment: What a game of codenames!

Comment: @DEEM Knowledge tag is also known as trivia

Comment: Now I feel bad about my games of Codenames, where 3 in a turn is considered a success.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The word is

> KING

The connections are

> King's COLLEGE
>  Stephen King (SCARY)
>  King of EGYPT
>  Billie Jean King (TENNIS; thanks @North)
>  MUSIC has plenty of "Kings", including Elvis Presley, BB King, Michael Jackson...
>  I have a DREAM (Martin Luther King)
>  King of ENGLAND
>  What kings do is LEAD

And the word has no connection to MUD, FACT, DEEP or BULB (that I can tell).

Comment: There's a really famous tennis player named Billie Jean King

Comment: Isn't there a KING'S college in England?

Comment: @North Yes, there are [a few](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King%27s_College)... ;)

Comment: @IanMacDonald That's an understatement :P

Comment: Answerers putting their solutions in spoiler tags is of little benefit if people then give the answer away in the comments.  Try being more indirect in alluding to the answer instead of saying or referencing it directly, or using [ROT-13](http://www.rot13.com/) encoding or similar if you must, to preserve the mystery for future would-be solvers. :)